# ZeroClipboard in bootstrap context menu - no hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, contextmenu, zeroclipboard

I'm trying to add context menu to my table.
I've added menu and all my actions are working, but I have problem with hover on menu.
I know that ZeroClipboard is adding invisible swf on top of button (link) so that element isn't getting `hover` effect.

Hee is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/jSTCV/14/

When You right click on table row and hover on first item You'll see nice hover effect, but second item don't have that effect until I add `context-hover` class.

```
ZeroClipboard.config({
    moviePath: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/1.3.2/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    forceHandCursor: true,
    debug: true,
    hoverClass: "context-hover" /*thanks @adeneo*/
});
```

and CSS:

```
.context-hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #262626;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

**How can I add hover effect to second item in my context menu (item with ZeroClipboard) without special class - using `:hover`?**

If I update bootstrap I must update my custom CSS, I would like to avoid remembering about it.

Comment: So now you've copied my answer and changed the question? There is no way to have Bootstrap affect the Flash movie that is on top of the element directly, that hoverClass option is the only option provided by zeroClipBoard to catch the mouse events on the Flash movie.

Comment: @adeneo - I've upvoted You answer. I found similar solution in docs, but I din't found anything about `:hover` pseudo-selector. So I changed a bit my question. You answer was correct, I don't know why You removed it. Please add it again.

Comment: You can't use the :hover pseudo selector, as it's not an element, it's Flash, but zeroClipBoard will let you use a class, and will apply those styles to the underlying element, and that's about the only way to do it. As far as I know there are no workarounds, and nothing really you can do with javascript or CSS, as stuff like that doesn't work on Flash objects.

Comment: @adeneo - Thanks! If You post this as an answer I'll be happy to mark it as correct, also could You remove down vote?